# no parallel threads with openMP

Tags: c++, openmp

My problem is that I get no parallelization with openMP.

My system: 
ubuntu 11.4
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz

Compiler: 
g++ Version: 4.5.2
with flag -fopenmp

With this code I see that there is only one thread:

```
int nthreads, tid, procs, maxt, inpar, dynamic, nested;

// Start parallel region 
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)   {

// Obtain thread number    
tid = omp_get_thread_num();

// Only master thread does this    
if (tid == 0) 
{
printf("Thread %d getting environment info...\n", tid);

// Get environment information 
procs = omp_get_num_procs();
nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
maxt = omp_get_max_threads();
inpar = omp_in_parallel();
dynamic = omp_get_dynamic();
nested = omp_get_nested();

// Print environment information 
printf("Number of processors = %d\n", procs);
printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
printf("Max threads = %d\n", maxt);
printf("In parallel? = %d\n", inpar);
printf("Dynamic threads enabled? = %d\n", dynamic);
printf("Nested parallelism supported? = %d\n", nested);  
}
}
```

because I see the following output:

```
Number of processors = 4
Number of threads = 1
Max threads = 4
In parallel? = 0
Dynamic threads enabled? = 0
Nested parallelism supported? = 0
```

What is the problem?

Can some one help, please?

Comment: Have you set the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable?

Comment: Hey!

No, I have not. But after doing omp_set_num_threads(2);

I got the following output:

    Number of processors = 4
    Number of threads = 1
    Max threads = 2
    In parallel? = 0
    Dynamic threads enabled? = 0
    Nested parallelism supported? = 0

number of threads is still 1.

Answer (score 5):

Your code works for me on Ubuntu 11.04 with the g++ compiler version 4.5.2 however I had to change

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)   {
```

to

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)  
{
```

for it to compile successfully.

EDIT: If fixing the syntax doesn't work my next idea would be to ask what is the exact command that you are using to compile code?

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)   {
```

is incorrect syntax, as noted by hrandjet

The pragma must end with a new line, so the { should be on the next line.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)   
{
```

This works for me on Windows XP.

Comment: So... you just posted a duplicate of @hrandjet's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is the output prefaced by

```
Thread 0 getting environment info...
```

If not, the problem is as stated above - the open bracket ( { ) must be on a new line. To prove this further, try initializing

```
int tid = 1
```

and see if the output still shows up. If not, the #pragma is being ignored by your compiler (probably because of the bracket issue).